# PHP: Add 1 to every number in string

Tags: php, regex

I've got a string like: 
"The delivery time will be 3-4 days. If you choose 'express' the delivery time will be 1-2 days. Pay within 30 days.".

How can I add 1 day to every number in the string without re-creating the string? The result should be:
"The delivery time will be 4-5 days. If you choose 'express' the delivery time will be 2-3 days. Pay within 31 days.".

Comment: What have you tried? Got any code to share?

Comment: What about 31 days?Shoud it go to 32?

Comment: `preg_replace_callback('/\d+/',function($n) {return intval($n)+1;},$input);` wow that was hard :D

Comment: It was `30` not `31`. @Mihai

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol ~ `return intval($n)+1;` will not work but `return intval($n[0])+1; ` will

Comment: @RamRaider That's what happens when I don't debug my snarky comments XD Forgot that it's JavaScript that passes individual parameters to the callback, not PHP.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.preg-replace-callback.php) to do that:

```
<?php 
$s = "The delivery time will be 3-4 days. If you choose 'express' the delivery time will be 1-2 days. Pay within 30 days.";

function callback($matches) {
    return $matches[0] + 1;
}

$pattern = '~([0-9]+)~';
$r = preg_replace_callback($pattern, 'callback', $s);
echo $r;

?>
```

[Here's a demo](http://rextester.com/QIOD54543)

Answer (score 2):

[`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php)

```
<?php
$str = "The delivery time will be 3-4 days. If you choose 'express' the delivery time will be 1-2 days. Pay within 30 days";
$str = preg_replace_callback(
    '([0-9]+)',
    function ($matches) {            
        return $matches[0]+1;
    },
    $str
);
echo $str;
?>
```

Comment: Why did you copy my answer?

Comment: @baao, no sir, I was working on it and didn't see your answer before posting it, this page was open. but it sure matches. sorry.